# How do you flush a Java serial InputStream?

Tags: java, serial-port, flush

I'm using JavaComm, and getting the inputStream from the serial port object.  I have a problem in that sometimes when the system starts up there are noise characters in the buffer that I do not want.  I want to initialize the serial port then somehow flush the input of all data before I begin my processing.

Is there any way to do that?

TY
Fred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How would a "flush()" method know what is garbage and what is real data?  Only you know, and your program should be prepared to ignore leading garbage.

EDIT: If you can be absolutely certain that all data in the input buffer prior to sending the request is garbage, then just read until there is no more input data -- i.e. flush it yourself.

Comment: I have a certain device that will only send me a response after a request.  I could therefore flush before sending the first request thereby guaranteeing the buffer is initially empty - I think.

Comment: The InputStream base class doesn't seem to have a flush method though.

Answer (score 2):

Before sending any requests to your device read all that you can. Once there's nothing left to read you can start sending requests.