# Serial port communication in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, serial-port

What is the right way to clear SerialPort before writing to it again in JAVA?

Comment: It would be best if you showed your code. Are you really using Spring-Boot with the serial port?

Comment: Yes I am using serial communication with  springboot

Comment: Most things depend on the case. It is unlikely that there will be a simple idea that applies in all cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the OutputStream of a SerialPort in java, without having to close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574820/how-to-clear-the-outputstream-of-a-serialport-in-java-without-having-to-close-i)

Comment: Thanks all actually issue with receiving side not on sending .

Comment: I have project using serial communication that collecting data from Arduino Mega 2560, firstly I'm try using RXTX library and move to JSerialComm library it's perfect library to communication because RXTX it's not stable some times lose the connection, I'm sked question her about this lib(RXTX). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601310/communication-with-serial-is-not-stable, perfect because (no need to choose COM port, No need to close and open port continuously, at to this it's native library.