# Communication with serial is not stable

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx, arduino-c++

I have a project on the Arduino environment, the idea of the project is to test a machine, the main code is designed in Arduino with HMI display using serial and also to save the test data in the Java program, the problem is that the connection is unstable and also it was verified in the Java program, the library that I use is jSerialComm.

Hint:

- We change the USB Cable.
- We change the operating system (Windows 10 pro based 64).
- We change the Arduino Card (ATmega2560).
- We Test Arduino within HMI, The problem still.
- We change Java Application Library From jSerialComm to RXTX, the problem still.

Comment: What does “unstable” mean?

Comment: I'm means when get connect via SerialCom and get disconnect (repeated this 3 times or up) the port can't listening. This problem actually accurately in Arduino without java application.